# Problems implementing Haskell's `map` function with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, haskell, polymorphism

I love using Haskell but am forced to use C++ for school assignments. I am writing my own library for C++ that emulates Haskell's Prelude functions so I can write in a more concise and functional style in C++ if I wish ([repo on GitHub](https://github.com/evanrelf/cpp-prelude/tree/65a4cd6af8e6dd25de11c536397a8727bf34d7cf)).

A problem I have run into is implementing functions like `map` that operate on lists. In Haskell, `String` is equivalent to `[Char]`, so you can use strings in functions that take lists. In C++, `std::string` is *not* the same thing as `std::vector<char>`, so I have to write multiple versions of functions to take `std::string` or `std::vector<Type>`. This works fine for functions like `filter` or `tail` because their input and output are the same type. But with `map`, I need to be able to transform a vector of `int`s into `char`s, or a `string` into a vector of `bool`s.

---

When trying to run a simple pig latin converter ([`pigLatin.cpp` on GitHub](https://github.com/evanrelf/cpp-prelude/blob/65a4cd6af8e6dd25de11c536397a8727bf34d7cf/examples/pigLatin.cpp)), the `unwords` function fails because `map` isn't working.

```
examples/pigLatin.cpp:20:29: error: no matching function for call to 'unwords'
  std::string translation = unwords(map(pigLatin, words(input)));
                            ^~~~~~~
examples/../prelude.hpp:591:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'const std::vector<std::string>'
      (aka 'const vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >') for 1st argument
  std::string unwords(const std::vector<std::string> &xs) {
              ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I write my `map` function such that it behaves like the one in Haskell ([`map` on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map)):

```haskell
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

I don't know enough about the nuances of C++ templates to figure this one out. This is what I have so far ([`map` from `prelude.hpp` on GitHub](https://github.com/evanrelf/cpp-prelude/blob/65a4cd6af8e6dd25de11c536397a8727bf34d7cf/prelude.hpp#L11-L53)):

```cpp
// map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
template <typename Function, typename Input, typename Output>
std::vector<Output> map(const Function &f, const std::vector<Input> &xs) {
  const int size = xs.size();
  std::vector<Output> temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    temp.push_back(f(xs[i]));
  }
  return temp;
}

// map :: (String -> a) -> String -> [a]
template <typename Function, typename Output>
std::vector<Output> map(const Function &f, const std::string &xs) {
  const int size = xs.size();
  std::vector<Output> temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    temp.push_back(f(xs[i]));
  }
  return temp;
}

// map :: (a -> String) -> [a] -> String
template <typename Function, typename Input>
std::string map(const Function &f, const std::vector<Input> &xs) {
  const int size = xs.size();
  std::string temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    temp += f(xs[i]);
  }
  return temp;
}

// map :: (String -> String) -> String -> String
template <typename Function>
std::string map(const Function &f, const std::string &xs) {
  const int size = xs.size();
  std::string temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    temp += f(xs[i]);
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I see is that in `template <typename Function, typename Input, typename Output>`, the relationship between `Function` and `Input` and `Output` is not specified.  How about `std::vector<Output> map(Func<Input,Output>, const std::vector<Input> &xs)`, for a suitable definition of `Func`.

Comment: @luqui C++ has SFINAE, which somewhat encourages the original style, I think, since it produces a more general template.

Comment: The issue here seems to be that `map(pigLatin, words(input))` is producing a string instead of a vector -- the wrong overload is being chosen.

Comment: @chi Exactly, and I don't know how to tell it to use the correct one.

Comment: `map` was working fine when I only allowed `std::vector<Type> -> std::vector<Type>` and `std::string -> std::string`. One I tried allowing them to cross over, it stopped working.

Comment: Really neat idea! And a great learning exercise. Two factors to consider: 1. Your `std::vector` implementations will be strictly evaluated, and to get lazy behavior, you would need a container with thunks. 2. If you’ll be copying a lot of large list elements, consider storing `std::shared_ptr<T>` in your vectors. So you might want a variant of `map` and catamorphisms that does this.

Comment: An interesting special case you can overload and optimize: if your function has the same input and output type, and the input `vector` is a non-const rvalue reference, you could create the output `vector` in-place.

Comment: Also, if the input is an rvalue, you could do an `.emplace_back(f(std::move(x)))` and possibly get a more-efficient implementation for some `f`. E.g., if `f` is scalar multiplication, you could get the behavior of `*=` rather than creating a temporary.

Comment: a bystander question: have you considered using iterators and std::transform? could it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this declaration:

```
template <typename Function, typename Input, typename Output>
std::vector<Output> map(const Function &f, const std::vector<Input> &xs);
```

`Output` is a non-deduced context. The compiler will deduce the type of `Function` and `Input` from the provided arguments, but `Output` cannot be deduced - it would have to be explicitly provided. That's not going to happen.

What you want to do is yourself compute what `Output` is as a function of `Function` and `Input`. With a C++17 compiler/library, that's [`std::invoke_result_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) (on C++11, use `result_of`). That is:

```
template <typename Function, typename Input,
    typename Output = std::invoke_result_t<Function const&, Input const&>>
std::vector<Output> map(const Function &f, const std::vector<Input> &xs);
```

It's a defaulted template parameter, but since the user won't actually ever provide it, the default argument will get used, which is what you want. Now this isn't entirely right either, since `invoke_result_t` could return something that you can't put in a `vector` (like, a reference). So we need to [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) it. Moreover, you'll want to reserve the output vector since we know up front what its size will be:

```
template <typename Function, typename Input,
    typename Output = std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<Function&, Input const&>>>
std::vector<Output> map(Function&& f, const std::vector<Input> &xs)
{
    std::vector<Output> res;
    res.reserve(xs.size());
    for (auto&& elem : xs) {
        res.push_back(f(elem));
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Now, if you want this to be able to take a `string` and either return a `vector<X>` *or* a `string`, that's now getting pretty complicated. You can't overload on return type in C++, so providing those two overloads is ill-formed. It happens to work in your case now, since the `string --> vector<X>` overload will be removed from consideration due to `X` not being deducible. But once you fix that, you'll run into that problem.

Comment: It sounds like this is the best answer. It's disappointing this is so tedious to deal with in C++. Is there no way to specify the type of the function argument? Something like `... map(const Function<int, bool> &f ...` to only accept functions that take an `int` and return a `bool`.

Comment: @evanrelf Well, you can take a `std::function<bool(int)>` but I'm not sure why you'd actually want to do that. Why do you think you need to specify the type of the function argument? You *really* don't.

Comment: So could I write `filter` using `std::function<bool(Type)>` to restrict the first argument to only functions that take the type that is in the container and return a `bool`?

Comment: @evanrelf No, don't do that. The right way to do that is to verify that `std::invoke_result_t<F, X>` is `bool` (or, really, is convertible to bool). (i.e. with `std::enable_if`)

Comment: @Barry In the future, do you think we will also include C++ concepts among the "right" ways?

Comment: @chi Once we have a compiler that implements the working draft's definitions of concepts, sure :-)